# Redis keys with incremental integer value

Tags: redis

I have key-values like following example:

```
KEY VALUE
key1    1
key2    2
key3    3
.       .
.       .
keyN    N
```

Each of my key needs to map a unique number so I am mapping my keys to auto incremented numbers then inserting it to Redis via [redis mass insertion](https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) which works very well and then using GET command for internal processing of all the key value mappings.

But I have more than 1 billion key so I was wondering is there even more efficient (mainly lesser memory usage) way for using Redis for this scenario?

Comment: your condition is to just have unique key right?

Comment: i have unique string keys and i need to map them integers. Then i want use this key value mapping with standard GET command.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: mainly consuming lesser memory

Comment: also by efficient means since my values belongs to keys are incremented numbers i thought maybe there is alternative way/usage in Redis so i don't need to set this auto incremented values.

Answer (score 1):

The auto-increment key allows a unique number to be generated when a new record is inserted into a table/redis.

There is other way using UUID.

But I think auto-increment is far better due to reason like it need four time more space, ordering cannot be done based on key,etc

Comment: in which table you mean in redis?

Answer (score 1):

You can pipeline commands into Redis to avoid the round-trip times like this:

```
{ for ((i=0;i<10000000;i++)) ; do printf "set key$i $i\r\n"; done ; sleep 1; } | nc localhost 6379
```

That takes 80 seconds to set 10,000,000 keys.

---

Or, if you want to avoid creating all those processes for `printf`, generate the data in a single `awk` process:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){printf("set key%d %d\r\n",i,i)}}'; sleep 1; } | nc localhost 6379
```

That now takes 17 seconds to set 10,000,000 keys.

Comment: thanks i am using pipeline and it works well just wonder is there any alternative for my string-number mapping usage.

Comment: @Tamer Maybe show your code then to make that clear to others since you don't mention pipe-lining in your question.

Comment: sure i have updated and mentioned about redis mass insertion which is pipe-lining in redis.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing exactly the same thing.
here is an simple example.
if you have a better one, welcome to discuss :)

## 1. connect to redis

```
import redis
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host=your_host, port=your_port)
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
```

## 2.define a function to incr, use pipe

```
def my_incr(pipe):
    next_value = pipe.hlen('myhash')
    pipe.multi()
    pipe.hsetnx(
        name='myhash',
        key=newkey, value=next_value
    )
```

## 3.make the function become a transaction

```
pipe = r.pipeline()
newkey = 'key1'
r.transaction(my_incr, 'myhash')
```

Comment: This is not the place for discussion. you can add comments if you are eligible enough for commenting. If you want to discuss use chat feature of stackoverflow, but that too requires 20 rep. I suggest you answer if you are pretty sure that your answer satisfies op's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be more memory efficient, you can use `HASH` to store these key-value pairs. Redis has special encoding for small `HASH`. It can save you lots of memory.

In you case, you can shard your keys into many small `HASH`s, each `HASH` has less than `hash-max-ziplist-entries` entries. See the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) for details.

B.T.W, with the `INCR` command, you can use Redis to create auto-incremented numbers.

Comment: thanks i have used HSET with 1 key which contained all my key-values but i didn't see the memory usage difference. maybe i should use all my keys as separate HSET key?

Comment: NO, you should have many small `HASH`s, each `HASH` has less than `hash-max-ziplist-entries` entries. If there're too many elements in a `HASH`, Redis won't use the special encoding.

Comment: With the special encoding, you can *use up to 10 times less memory (with 5 time less memory used being the average saving)*

Comment: oh got you i need to shard my keys but in that case when i make HGET i need to know which key is in which shard i will think about how can i shard my keys. and what happens if i increase     hash-max-ziplist-entries values?

Comment: my keys has not got any specific pattern to shard but if you have any suggestion about sharding let me know thanks.

Comment: 1. If you increase `hash-max-ziplist-entries ` too much, you might get performance problem, i.e. much slower. 2. Use some hash function, e.g. MurmurHash, to hash your key to an integer, and shard with that integer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my own question.

If you have sorted key values, the most efficient way to bulk insert and then read them is using a B-Tree based database.

For instance, with MapDB I am able to insert it very quickly and it takes up less memory.